# Create apache.config in .ebextensions but it does not work

Tags: apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, httpd.conf

I created an apache.config in .ebextensions to extend the keep-alive setting of apache but I don't see the file in /etc/httpd/conf.d in my instance. My attempt is like:

My instance ver.: Amazon Linux 2/3.3.5

```
files:
    "/etc/httpd/conf.d/timeout.conf" :
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            Timeout 300
            KeepAliveTimeout 300
```

```
xxxxxxx@ip-172-30-2-176 current]$ ls -l /etc/httpd/conf.d
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 62 Oct  9 02:59 elasticbeanstalk
```

Also, I have run `httpd -t -D DUMP_CONFIG 2>/dev/null | grep -v '#'` to check the values but these values are 60(default value).

Any suggestions for what I might be doing wrong?
Many thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by myself to change creating the timeout.conf file and move it in .platform folder like this.

I'm not sure why, but my case, I put it in elasticbeanstalk folder to be with the confs from the elastic beanstalk.

```
~/my-app/
|-- .ebextensions/
|
`-- .platform/
    |-- httpd/
        |-- conf.d
            |-- elasticbeanstalk
                |-- timeout.conf
```